# Creating a table out of columns of unequal lengths (retrieved from different selects)

Tags: sql

I have two select statements, that spit out two results.

First Select:

```
select ColA from TableA A where A.col1 = 'blah'

|ColA  |
|------|
|  1   |
|  2   |
```

Second select:

```
select locations from LocationTable

| Locations   |
|-------------|
|   Texas     |
|   Colorado  |
|   Missouri  |
|   Kansas    |
```

New table #Final should look like,

```
| ColA        |   Locations    |
|-------------|----------------|
|    1        |     Texas      |
|    1        |     Colorado   |
|    1        |     Missouri   |
|    1        |     Kansas     |
|    2        |     Texas      |
|    2        |     Colorado   |
|    2        |     Missouri   |
|    2        |     Kansas     |
```

> Note:
>   The Insert statement should utilize the selects to get the above result.
>   Thanks in advance !

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `cross join`:

```
select a.colA, l.location
from tableA a cross join
     locations l;
```

In most databases, you can say:

```
create table t as
    select a.colA, l.location
    from tableA a cross join
         locations l;
```

In some (such as SQL Server) you use `into`:

```
select a.colA, l.location
into t
from tableA a cross join
     locations l;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `cross join` :

```
select a.colA, l.location 
from TableA a cross join
     LocationTable l
where . . .;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a cross join:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA A
CROSS JOIN tableB B
WHERE A.ColA IN ('1', '2', 'blah');
```